# Is $\bf{u} \times\bf{(\nabla \times u)}$ $=0$ in the contex for deriving Bernoulli’s theorem

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

Is $\bf{u} \times\bf{(\nabla \times u)}$ $=0$

I am trying to derive the to Bernoulli’s theorem for a a steady, inviscid, homogeneous, incompressible fluid.

Using mass conservation:

> [image]

Using Euler's equation:

> [image: Blockquote]

Now somehow we get that $\nabla H$ is zero, i don't understand how?

Answer (score 1):

What is true is that $ u \cdot \nabla H = 0$. This is all that is required, as Bernoulli’s principle says that the quantity $H$ is conserved along streamlines.